# How can I remove FRP(google account) in EDL mode(Emergency Download mode) for android devices using Python?

Tags: python, android, frp

should I use Fastboot commands or anything else like  EDL commands
Is there any EDL commands like fastboot command that I can use in Subprocess??
Please help me friends

Im making a program to remove google account in EDL mode